# Android BroadcastReceiver start activity

Tags: android, android-activity, receiver

With this BroadcastReceiver I can launch an activity every time the device screen turns off. The only problem is that the same activity is started 2 times. I do not understand the issue

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {    

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            intent = new Intent(context, Login2.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);               
        }
    }
}
```

start receiver into oncreate of activity

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
```

manifest

```
<receiver android:name="utils.ScreenReceiver"
          android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: are you regitering/unregistering the receiver in activity's lifecycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are effectively registering two instances of your `ScreenReceiver` and thus responding twice, and creating two versions of your `Activity`. You are first registering it system wide using the `<intent-filter>` applied in your manifest. Secondly, you are registering a different instance of `ScreenReceiver` with your call to `registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);`. You should only use one mechanism for registering your `BroadcastReceiver`.

Also, make sure you are making a call to unregister the receiver if you stick with the `Activity` `registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);` method.